# Help me to undertand some physical problem of rotating water

Tags: analysis, physics, rotations

It comes from the chapter 5 execise of Mathematical Analysis 1 by Vladimir Zorich.

Below is the problem:

A glass of water is rotating about its axis at constant angular velociry $\omega$.

Let $y=f(x)$ denote the equation of the curve obtained by cutting the surface of the liquid with a plane passing through its axis of rotation.

a) Show that $f'(x)=\frac{w^2}gx$, where $g$ is the acceleration of free fall.

b) Choose a function $f(x)$ that satisfies the condition given in part a).

c) Does the condition on the function $f(x)$ given in part a) change if its axis of rotation does not coincide with the axis of the glass?

These are my question about this problem.

First, I'm not sure what "cutting the surface of the liquid with a plane passing through its axis of rotation." means.

I think that looks like one of these two pictures.
[image]

Which is the right "figure" which describes the situation of this probblem? and I can't imagine how the glass look likes, does glass means that rectangular shape one?

Second, I couldn't set up the equation. I guess it has to be related with $sin, cos$ functions and $\omega$ will be included in the argument of $sin, cos$.

My guess is $<x(t),y(t)>=<r(t)sin(\omega*t)$,$r(t)cos(\omega*t)$>.

where $r(t)=$ (the distance of the point and the center of circle). So I guess (A) picture is the problem situation.

But I can't give you why it should look like this. and this equation is based on the assumption that a glass looks like cylinder. Could you give me a reason or if it's false, what is the right equation?

Comment: Imagine a glass sitting on a turntable. It is spinning with it. The glass is a cylinder and is rotating around its axis. The water in the glass is also rotating, at the same angular velocity. Initially it might slush a little, but due to viscosity, eventually it will settle into a static (with respect to the glass) configuration. The water-air surface is a 2-d surface which has an equation $y = F(x,z)$, where $y$ is the "up" direction and $x,z$ are the horizontal ones. You have to investigate the curve $y = f(x) = F(x, 0)$, which is the intersection of $F(x,z)$ with the plane $z = 0$.

Comment: You are looking for this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88340/fluid-in-a-rotating-cylinder or google for "mechanics of fluids glass rotating liquid paraboloid".